# Is selector options built in to make complex decisions using nightwatchjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

Using the JavaScript Selenium tool called NightWatch, what is a good practice to determine parts of the GUI before applying a test? For example finding if on A or B then having separate tests. Another example, determine if logged in, so you don't keep logging in etc. Seems when I use `if` statement with selectors, it wants to fail if I get the `else` option.

I have used Python API for a long time, and you have access to all Python libraries, you can use the Selenium Selectors to verify, without resulting in an error etc. I have even used the npm Selenium API with similar results, though still green to how it works, but I can not get the layer of NightWatch to do much else but an E2E pass or fail no matter what I attempt.

I figure I would put it out there so I can see if I am simply doing it wrong or if this is a common issue. Or, maybe there are other libraries designed to assist what I am looking for. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a generic example in Python I might use to verify A/B options that works...

```
# so you know what EC is
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...

try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#foo')))
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#blah1 a').click()
except:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#blah2 a').click()
```

And another maybe cleaner looking way to do it in Python...

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#blah1 a')) > 0:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#blah1 a').click()
else:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#blah2 a').click()
```

There is obviously more logic here needed as it does not have all the built ins that nightwatch has, but this should give some idea what I am trying to do.

Comment: Can you provide an example with the JS or Python API showing the behaviour that you are unable replicate with nightwatchjs?

Comment: @FlorentB. I just offered a very generic try exception hack used in Python to accomplish this. That is essentially the goal here, not seeing if you can access one of these, but determining what option is available to you and using it. Then from that point making your assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional statements with Nightwatch.js but it needs to be placed in the callback since the programming is asynchronous.
Here is an example to click on a link and assert the title depending on the presence of an element:

```
client
  .url('http://stackoverflow.com/')
  .elements('css selector', '#abcd', function(result) {
      if (result.value.length) {  // if element is present
          client.click('#nav-questions');
          client.assert.title("Newest Questions - Stack Overflow");
      } else {
          client.click('#nav-askquestion');
          client.assert.title("Ask a Question - Stack Overflow");
      }
  })
  .end();
```